# Binding to json payload AND headers of http trigger in Azure Functions

Tags: azure-functions

How can you specify a Http-triggered Azure Function with two strongly typed objects constructed from the `HttpRequest`, the first being a User object from a decoded `JWT` passed in the headers, and the second a `json` payload from the `POST` body.

```
    [FunctionName("SomeRequest")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post")]
        AuthorisedUser user,
        SomeRequestDto jsonPayload,
        ILogger log)
    {
        // some logic here
        return new OkObjectResult("OK");
    }
```